# Prompting the user to enter Name value pairs and then printing it out using a Name_value class

Tags: c++

I am learning from Bjarne Stroustrup's book for beginners and I on Chapter 6 Exercise 4 as seen below. I am studying it alone and I need some reviews.

Are my comments any good?

Can you recommend me some improvements regarding comments or overusing functions?

The writer of the book has [some solutions](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/Solutions/Ch6/e6-4.cpp) for his exercise and he doesn't use the `put_in` function for example.

Are global variables that bad? I used it when declaring `vector<Name_value>pairs`.

```
/*
4. Define a class Name_value that holds a string and a value. Rework exercise 19 in Chapter 4 to use a
vector<Name_value> instead of two vectors.

Chapter 4 : 19. Write a program where you first enter a set of name-and-value pairs, such as Joe 17 and Barbara 22. For each pair, add
the name to a vector called names and the number to a vector called scores (in corresponding positions, so that if
names[7]=="Joe" then scores[7]==17). Terminate input with NoName 0. Check that each name is unique and
terminate with an error message if a name is entered twice. Write out all the (name,score) pairs, one per line.
*/

#include "../../std_lib_facilities.h"

const string print_names = "NoName";
const int print_val = 0;

//class of the name and corresponding value
class Name_value {
public:
    string Name;        //the name of the person
    int value;          //their respective score
    Name_value(string Na, int val) 
        :Name(Na), value(val) { }
};
vector<Name_value>pairs;        //the list of names and their corresponding values

//put the pairs in the vector
vector<Name_value> put_in(string x, int y) {
    pairs.push_back(Name_value(x,y));
    return pairs;
}

int main()
try
{
    string names;
    int scores;
    cout << "Enter 'NoName' and score '0' when you want to print out the results!\n";
    cout << "Please enter some names and their scores (Ex.: Joe 22 Anne 53): ";
    while (cin) {
        cin >> names >> scores;
        if (!cin) error("You have not entered a string and then a value!\n");
        if (names == print_names && scores == print_val) {
            cout << "The list of pairs entered: \n";
            for (int i = 0; i < pairs.size(); i++) {
                 cout << pairs[i].Name << '\t' << pairs[i].value << '\n';
            }
            break;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < pairs.size(); i++)
        {
            if (names == pairs[i].Name) error("Duplicates found!\n");
        }
        pairs = put_in(names, scores); //put the values into the vector list
    }
}
catch (exception&e)
{
    cerr << "error: " << e.what() << '\n';
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: [`std_lib_facilities.h`](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/std_lib_facilities.h) in case anyone wants to look at it.

Comment: @VladarAkos, how the program terminates? Is there a way to gracefully exit rather than pressing `X` on the window or ctrl+C to kill it?

Comment: @Incomputable Well after printing the result there is a break which prompts the user to enter any key to exit the console window. Is that a good option or should I do something else?

Comment: @VladarAkos, oh, sorry, missed it. It is totally fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Yes, global variables really [are that bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484635/are-global-variables-bad). Do try to avoid them.
- Personally I find it easier to read if you add some vertical space to your member initializer list like so:

  ```
  Foo(int a, int b)
      : a{a}
      , b{b}
  {}
  ```
- Don't omit braces as that can lead to hard to find bugs (For example Apple's [*goto fail bug*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unreachable_code) would have been much easier to spot if braces had been used.
- [Prefer prefix over postfix](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/59880/avoid-postfix-increment-operator)
- It's okay to use whitespace more leniently

  ```
  // This might be debatable
  pairs.push_back(Name_value(x,y));

  // But this just looks strange
  catch (exception&e)
  ```

  Considering that you add a space everywhere else in the code you might as well add one in those cases.
- Your naming could be improved. Namely `put_in`, `x` and `y` are not the greatest variable names. Also why is `Name` capitalized? Why `names` and `scores` when they only hold one name/score? Remember that variable names should always reflect intent as your goal is to write self-documenting code.
- This code is confusing

  ```
  pairs = put_in(names, scores); //put the values into the vector list
  ```

  First get rid of that comment. Second, why are you returning the vector after you already added the values to it? Why even use a function for this in the first place? Simply doing:

  ```
  pairs.push_back(Name_value(names, scores));
  ```

  Has the same effect.
- While you didn't write it, you still use `using namespace std` included via the header file provided by Bjarne(?).
  Just a reminder that this [is considered bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)
  but hopefully it will be explained further into the book as well.
- I'm no expert on exceptions but the way you use them seems wonky, maybe someone else can chime in here.

Comment: Thank you for all your suggestions. They are very much appreciated. By omitting braces you mean when I have one declaration after an if then I should put braces as well? I haven't even heard of prefix over postfix until now so thank you for that. I don't really get your point about whitespace. So I should use more for readability? I know that using namespace std is bad but it is in the header provided so I cannot do much about until. The exception is indeed wonky. It is from the header aswell. The author provided it for some early exception handling. There a chapter on exceptions coming soon.

Comment: Can I maybe edit my code above with your suggestions and ask for your feedback again? (if that isn't a problem of course)

Comment: @VladarAkos No. Editing a question invalidates answers so you may not edit your question. You can however rewrite your program based on input from CR and then ask another question.

Comment: @VladarAkos about exceptions, you are just re-implementing the default behaviour. Try running `int main() {const  auto a =  new int[99999999999999999];}`